# How to compare 2 different objects with different fields and create a new object with a new field that tells common elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have

```
obj1= [{keyID: 'c71cc89335565241f59ac9bb9da162a3ddf4a6b483bdc06dd82b9275898ba5ee', name: 'user1@mail.com'},
 {keyID: '34051d2554ab20b0d24c2c39946d96da7e07508e7a8546bc2df299601dcbff05', name: 'user2@mail.com'}]
```

And

```
obj2=[{id: 19, email: 'user4@mail.com', other_field: false},
  {id: 221, email: 'user3@mail.com', other_field: false},
{id: 13, email: 'user2@mail.com', other_field: false)},
 {id: 2, email: 'user1@mail.com', other_field: true]
```

As you can see I have for `obj1 keyID` that is diffenret from `obj2 ID` and that is fine. The thing that I want to group them by is name(obj1) and email(obj2)
the field with the same email should create a new object with the same structure obj2 with a new field "`isPresent`"

```
result=[{id: 19, email: 'user4@mail.com', other_field: false,isPresent=false},
  {id: 221, email: 'user3@mail.com', other_field: false,isPresent=false},
{id: 13, email: 'user2@mail.com', other_field: false,isPresent=true)},
 {id: 2, email: 'user1@mail.com', other_field: true,isPresent=true]
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over `obj2` and check if an element with the same name exists in `obj1` via [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

I also [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the `obj` inside the map instead of assigning `isPresent` directly to avoid side effects.

```js
const obj1 = [{ keyID: 'c71cc89335565241f59ac9bb9da162a3ddf4a6b483bdc06dd82b9275898ba5ee', name: 'user1@mail.com' }, { keyID: '34051d2554ab20b0d24c2c39946d96da7e07508e7a8546bc2df299601dcbff05', name: 'user2@mail.com' }];
const obj2 = [{ id: 19, email: 'user4@mail.com', other_field: false }, { id: 221, email: 'user3@mail.com', other_field: false }, { id: 13, email: 'user2@mail.com', other_field: false }, { id: 2, email: 'user1@mail.com', other_field: true }];
const result = obj2.map((obj) => ({
  ...obj,
  isPresent: obj1.some(({ name }) => name === obj.email),
}));
console.log(result);
```